# How to insert a column while iterating a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['new_column'] = caculate_value(row)
```

Like above, I want to insert a new column for each row. How to put this row with new column back to the df?

Comment: kindly share sample dataset and provide expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `apply` function outside of the loop like below

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['new_column'] = caculate_value(row)

df['new_column'] = df.apply(calculate_value, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(calculate_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: Should this use outside of the loop or inside it?

Comment: This gives the same value for each row! not individual values

Comment: ```apply``` is in lieu of the loop. Remove the loop entirely.